# Multiple Powershell Progress Bars (Nested?)

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I'm looking for a way to display multiple progress bars, one for an outer loop and one for an inner. I have a script that Loops through a big list of custom objects, and for each of those objects I have an inner loop that performs actions on a list that is an attribute of those objects.

Script Example:

```
$ListOfIDs.Keys |
Show-Progress | #Outer Loop - ProgressBar1
% {
    $entityName = $_
    $TableIndex = $ListOfEntities.Name.IndexOf($entityName)
    $TableNameList = $ListOfEntities[$TableIndex].Group.RoleTable

    $ListOfIDS[$_] |
    Show-Progress | #Inner Loop - ProgressBar2
    % {
        $ID = $_.ID
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            EntityName = $entityName
            Id = $ID
            Roles =  $TableNameList | Function-FooBar -ID $ID
        }
    }
}
```

Show-Progress Function:

```
function Show-Progress
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [PSObject[]]$InputObject
)

    [int]$TotItems = $Input.Count
    [int]$Count = 0

    $Input|foreach {
        $_
        $Count++
        [int]$PercentComplete = ($Count/$TotItems* 100)
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing items" -PercentComplete $PercentComplete -Status ("Working - " + $PercentComplete + "%")
    }
}
```

Here is a quick example of what I am looking for : [image: ProgressExample]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the parameter `-ParentId` and `-Id` to accomplish that. At the Outer Loop you assign the ID 1, and at the Inner Loop you specify as `ParentId` the value 1.

Comment: This achieves what I wanted perfectly, I cant believe I never noticed the parent property, feel stupid now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/write-ProgressEx

https://github.com/mazzy-ax/Write-ProgressEx

sample:

```
$outer = 1..20
$inner = 1..50

write-ProgressEx "pipe nodes" -Total $outer.Count
$outer | write-ProgressEx -Status "outer" | ForEach-Object {

    write-ProgressEx "pipe names" -Total $inner.Count -id 1
    $inner | write-ProgressEx -id 1 -status "inner" | ForEach-Object {
        # ....
    }

}
write-ProgressEx #close all progress bars
```

[image]